# WordPress - Single post not pulling in head

Tags: php, wordpress

I have built a wordpress template based of the 2011 theme. I seem to have gone wrong somewhere... On a single post, I am not pulling in the head.

I have completely deleted single.php in attempt to track down the problem and the page still displays the same.

Here is the page I am referring to ...

http://bost.themediafeed.com/taken-on-a-recent-lunch-and-learn-tour-of-the/attachment/372/

```
<?php

/**
* The Header for our theme.
*
* Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
*
 * @package WordPress
 *
*/

?><!DOCTYPE html>



<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title><?php

/*

 * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.

 */

global $page, $paged;



wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );



// Add the blog name.

bloginfo( 'name' );



// Add the blog description for the home/front page.

$site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );

if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )

    echo " | $site_description";



// Add a page number if necessary:

if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )

    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyeleven' ), max( $paged, $page ) );



?></title>

<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<![endif]-->

<?php


if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )

    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );


wp_head();

?>

</head>
```

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Comment: You might want to ask this question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're linking to an attachment page, not a post. If no specific attachment pages exist, I believe attachments default to the page.php template.